# Ejecutar servicio Android indefinidamente

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio

Buenas tardes, tengo una duda con mi código Android, estuve revisando preguntas que otras personas han realizado en esta pagina y todos preguntan sobre ejecutar la tarea en segundo plano o que se ejecute a pesar de cerrar la aplicación, pero mi pregunta es ***¿como puedo hacer que el servicio se ejecute repetidamente hasta que mande a llamar el onDestroy?***

Actualmente lo estoy manejando con un ciclo `for` pero esto solo me ejecuta la tarea hasta que termina la cuenta y después la cierra, ya intente al final del `for` restarle **1** a la variable condición, pero entonces la aplicación me manda error y se cierra.

¿Alguna idea?

**Este es el código de mi servicio:**

```
public class ServicioBuscador extends Service {

    int a=0,calificando=0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        for(int x=1;x<=20;x++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ServicioBuscador.this, "aun no: "+x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BuscarA();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void BuscarA(){
        if(a<=20){
                Toast.makeText(ServicioBuscador.this, "Contar: "+a , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            UnSegundo();
                a=a+1;
        }else{
            NotificacionPositiva();
        }

    }
    private void UnSegundo(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
```

Pero de esta manera el servicio solo se ejecuta durante 20 segundos y al terminar de contar o bien, cuando **a=20** deja de ejecutarse el servicio.

Comment: Pero para que quieres que se ejecute indefinidamente? y quieres que muera el servicio al presionar un botón o que acción ?

Comment: Cuando realices preguntas es importante agregar el error que te muestra la aplicación, esta información es importante para los desarrolladores que pretendan ayudarte.

Comment: Claro!, gracias, la cuestión es que no me arroja errores, como explico anteriormente la aplicación no funciona si al final del ciclo For resto 1 a la variable condición, pero si entiendo que es por que se crea un bucle infinito, pero de otra manera me funciona correctamente siempre y cuando yo le indique cuantas veces repetirse.

Comment: Asi es @Ash quiero utilizar el servicio para que realice búsquedas en mi base de datos cada x minutos, y si encuentra un registro con estatus "pendiente" mande una notificación para avisarle al usuario que encontró un registro pendiente y detenga el servicio, después de que el usuario realice el proceso que necesita ese registro volverá a la pantalla de inicio y se ejecutara el servicio de nuevo.

Comment: Es importante definas cuando deseas detener el servicio? Que acción?

Comment: No entendí bien tus preguntas Jorgesys, ¿Es importante definas cuando deseas detener el servicio?
No, de echo, lo que necesito es que el servicio se ejecute hasta que se mande a llamar el onDestroy.
¿Que acción?
Se va a realizar una búsqueda en una base de datos, y si encuentra un registro entonces manda a llamar el onDestroy

Comment: Jorge te pregunta en que acción deseas detener tu servicio, si es "obvio" cuando llames al onDestroy pero en acción lo vas a llamar, cuando presiones un botón o que cosa, al parecer, tu lo que quieres hacer que el servicio busque cada x tiempo en tu base y si encuentra un registro pendiente te envie una notificación, pero creo yo lo que debes hacer es llamar el servicio cada x tiempo en tu Oncreate, es una opción

Comment: La acción es lo que había comentado,  básicamente es una sentencia IF, si encuentra un registro en la base de datos entonces manda a llamar al onDestroy, de lo contrario espera x minutos y vuelve a buscar.

No lo he intentado como recomiendas pero me parece que si mandas a llamar al servicio desde el onCreate entonces no se ejecuta en segundo plano, necesitas tener la aplicación abierta para que se ejecute ¿no? 

¿Te refieres al onCreate del MainActivity o al onCreate del servicio?

Comment: Estoy, en otras palabras intentando que el servicio se ejecute como si fuera un WHILE (que se ejecute hasta que una condición se cumpla), actualmente me funciona como si fuera un FOR (yo le tengo que indicar cuantas veces se va a ejecutar).

Comment: si quieres que se ejecute siempre no puedes poner un while(bool) y cuando lo quieras parar pasas ese booleano a false

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano  no entendí bien tu comentario ¿es pregunta o me sugieres que use un while?

Comment: si quieres hacer algo de manera indefinida es mejor un while que un for y para lo que comentas que sería hacer algo indefinidamente hasta que tu decidas pararlo (es como lo entiendo) yo lo haría con un while y cuando quieras parar haz que no se cumpla la condición.